# How to connect to a dockerized PostgreSQL from (an undockerized) Python app

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-postgresql) to install PostgreSQL through Docker. In fact, I have used the following two commands:

```
Run
    docker run --name postgresql -d sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-2

Login
    sudo docker exec -it postgresql sudo -u postgres psql
```

Then I do `\conninfo` and I get:

```
# You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432"
```

What I would like to do next (but not sure how) is to connect into that database thought an external Python application that runs on my local machine (as opposed to another docket).

Should I shoot for `localhost:5432` or there is something missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [export the port](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) for postgresql, and then you can connect to it as if it were running locally.

```
docker run --name postgresql -d -p 5432:5432 sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-2
```

If you don't understand the link above, I suggest you read through the [getting starting guide](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/#running-a-web-application-in-docker).

Answer (score 2):

As @Burhan Khalid said, you can expose your container port using:

```
docker run --name postgresql -d -p 5432:5432 sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-2
```

To connect to PostgreSQL container, you can direct connect to: `127.0.0.1:5432`. You can't use `localhost:5432`, because it will try to find a socket file in your host (the socket file is in container).

Another solution is use your container IP address. To find the container IP address, you can use:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <your-container-id>
```

But, if you restart your container, the container will get a new IP. So, you need to reconfigure your database config.